# How can I sort elements of a vector by row using std::sort

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to sort the elements of a vector by row with the size of each row being different, for example if I have a

```
vector v = { 
             {5, 3, 1, 2},
             {10, 1},
             {3, 2, 1},
             {4, 3, 2, 0}
}


final vector = { {1, 2, 3, 5},
                 {1, 10},
                 {1, 2, 3},
                 {0, 2, 3, 4}
}
```

How can I do this using std::sort function?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
vector< vector<int> > v;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    sort(&v[i][i], &v[i][i] + n*m, less<int>());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by row? Is it a vector of vectors?

Comment: Yes it is a vector of vectors.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Since the sizes of each row are different, you can use vector<vector<int>> and sort the inner vectors in a loop

Comment: I tried this seeing one of the other threads on SO but I think it only works for a N*N vector for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  sort(&vector[i][i], &vector[i][i] + n*m, less<int>());
 }

Comment: Instead of putting your algorithm in the comment you should put it in the question with some readable formatting.

Comment: It does not look like a vector of vectors. Give the definition of 'vector' to get better answers.

Comment: @RahulNarayanan please update your tried result to main question. The code is so hard to read in the comment.

Comment: @panicsheep This is the vector I defined vector< vector<int> > v; I think this is a vector of vector.

Comment: Take a look at the example at the C++ reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

You have an array instead of a vector, but they are very similar. If you have any specific implementation problems you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: @RahulNarayanan just put the code in the question too so people can see everything easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to hold your data. Let's assume this change has been made.

Your ultimate goal is to sort each vector in your outer vector. This is perfectly easy with `std::sort`.

If you'd like to do it in-place, just call sort on each vector in the vector within a for-loop.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs = { 
    {5, 3, 1, 2},
    {10, 1},
    {3, 2, 1},
    {4, 3, 2, 0}
};

for(auto& v: vs) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

[Ideone it](http://ideone.com/2Y092g).

Similarly, but much less readable, is the use of `std::for_each` to apply `std::sort` to each element in the outer vector.

The [ideone](http://ideone.com/fic9RR) is included for this approach, but I'd caution to use the less verbose and more readable version above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ( auto& items:v)
 std::sort(items.begin(),items.end(),[](int lhs,int rhs) { return lhs<rhs; } );
```

Comment: You can drop the lambda: `std::sort` uses `operator <` by default.

Comment: @Quentin: Agreed, snippet  just for the sake of clarity or one can do descending sorting too

Comment: @seccpur for descending, `std::greater` would be more concise than a lambda.

Comment: What are you referring to with those squared brackets?

Comment: @RahulNarayanan That's called a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).